# Google Apps Scripting: How see the version number of a Google Sites page on the page itself

Tags: version-control, google-apps-script, google-sites

I want to see the version number of a Google Sites page on the page itself. I am talking about the numbers you see when you click the "More" button, then select "Revision History".

I am OK with any method to solve the problem, however currently I am trying to solve the problem with Google Apps Scripting.

I am able to see the last update time of the page by embedding the script below to the page:

```
   function doGet(e){
      var app= UiApp.createApplication();
      var page = SitesApp.getActivePage();
      app.add(app.createHTML('Last updated: ' + page.getLastUpdated().toISOString()));
      return app;
   }
```

The problem is, I could not find a `getVersion()` like method.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this for several reasons.

The page version is hosted in this variable inside the google site pages. 
webspace.page.revision

This is a good news but you can't access it.

1) If you try to access it using html box, the content of your html will be sanitized by caja and you will not access this variable.

2) If you try to build a javascript code and put it in an Apps Script caja will also forbid you to use variables from the parent frame. Even if you use SandboxMode.NATIVE.

3) If you try to put this code in some other site and include it as an iframe the content will be striped by your browser because of cross domain restrictions.

Sorry to say but what you want is impossible with todays caja restrictions.

Comment: OK. Thx. At least I know that it can not be done, now.